# Insomnia upload pic and post data at same time

Tags: rest, file, file-upload, binary, insomnia

I'm having problem posting binary data and regular data at the same time.

How I can test it with Insomnia? Insomnia offers only URL Encoded for data and Binary File for file. I cannot send both at the same time.

What should I do to test uploading data and binary file at the same time with one request?

Comment: could you check this question and accept the correct answer? its for the community
[help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: why did you chose byte, not Multipart ?

Answer (score 68):

you could use multipart form from insomnia
with this you could send data and file at the same request

[image]

Comment: When I do this with a CSV, Insomnia sends the contents of my file, not the file itself

Comment: nice found, [make a ticket or open an issue to them maybe,](https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues)

Answer (score 23):

1. Choose **Multipart Form**
   [image]
2. Enter the name of the param (ex. image) and for the value, at the end you have a dropdown, choose **File**
   [image]

BONUS:

If you want to upload multiple files, you just need to put the same name of the param.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! The key here was the dropdown that I hadn't noticed.